# Get information from SQL Server database with ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm developping an application with C# and ADO.Net entity data model.

I have a table `Users` in my SQL Server database with 3 columns (`idUser, nameUser, statusUser`).

What is the code to retrieve the first user of the table that has `statusUser = 0` and show her name in a label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to be using Entity Framework, that code would be something like this:

```
using (YourDatabaseContext context = new YourDatabaseContext())
{
    User firstUser = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.statusUser == 0);

    if (firstUser != null)
    {
        lblUserName.Text = firstUser.nameUser;
    } 
}
```

You should definitely check out some of the introductory tutorials on Entity Framework:

- [An Introduction to Entity Framework for absolute beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363040/An-Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-for-Absolute-B)
- [ADO.NET Entity Framework Tutorial and Basics](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/net30/article.php/c15489/ADONET-Entity-Framework-Tutorial-and-Basics.htm)

or just search on Google or Bing for `Entity Framework introductory tutorial` - there are **thousands** of those out there!